# Call an asynchronous method in a synchronous

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public Document updateFiasByFileName(String fileName){
        startUpdate(fileName);
    }

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void startUpdate(String fileName) {
        // A lot of code....
    }
}
```

The startUpdate method does not work asynchronously. I understand that this is due to the context in which it is called. If you move the asynchronous method to another service, then everything will start working fine. But how do I get this code to work correctly in one service? And will this be normal in terms of application architecture and code style?

Answer (score 2):

> But how do I get this code to work correctly in one service?

Simply put: You can't.

> 3. The @Async Annotation
>      First – let's go over the rules – @Async has two limitations:
>
>    1. it must be applied to public methods only
>    2. self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won't work
>
> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

(Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

My usual solution for this kind of problem is creating a second class, calling it e.g. `AsyncServiceImplFacade` that only contains the call to the original method similar to

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public Document updateFiasByFileName(String fileName){
        // A lot of code...
    }
}

@Service
public class AsyncServiceImplFacade {

    @Autowired
    ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void startUpdate(String fileName) {
        this.serviceImpl.updateFiasByFileName(fileName);
    }
}
```

acting like a asynchronous facade for clients that need asynchronous execution whilst others can use the original service for synchronous execution.

Comment: Your code leads to the creation of circular dependencies. This is due to the mutual introduction of classes into each other. A possible solution to my question is to use lookup methods. Or creating a bean and injecting it through BeanDefinition. But so far I have not done it. It seems my question was closed. It’s a pity, because I’m not asking if this can be done, but I’m looking for a way to do it.

Comment: `ServiceImpl` has no knowledge of `AsyncServiceImplFacade`, where should the circular dependency come from?